# How to remove custom block parent div's?

Tags: theming, blocks

I have created custom block in my custom module. I have created block template file into module templates folder. Custom block content coming successfully as per given in block__MODULENAME__dummmy_xyz.tpl.php file. I have only added following code into my block tpl file:

```
<div class="wrapperDummy">Hello</div>
```

But it is coming with block parent div's, Block id and block-inner tag. I dont want to show those extra div's.
Following is the hook_theme which I have in my module file:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MODULENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

    $items = array();

    $items['MODULENAME_dummmy_xyz_block_theme'] = array(
        'type' => 'theme',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'block__MODULENAME__dummmy_xyz',
        'variables'  => array()
    );
    return $items;
}
```

I am rendering block into tpl using,

```
$block = block_load('MODULENAME','dummmy_xyz');
print drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
```

block.tpl.php code:

```
<?php print $outer_prefix . $inner_prefix; ?>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>

  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $content_processed; ?>

  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php print $inner_suffix . $outer_suffix; ?>
```

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

`_block_get_renderable_array` function render default block theme where I couldn't remove parent element, So I made it by using module_invoke function:

```
$block = module_invoke('custom_module_name', 'block_view', 'block_name');
              print render($block['content']);
```